# PAC file return statement with "+" sign

Tags: proxy, pac

I saw a PAC file written like this

```
toky1 = "PROXY webproxy2.mycompany.com:8080; ";
dirext = "PROXY webproxy1.mycompany.com:8080; "; 

if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "10.1.33.0", "255.255.255.0")) {
return toky1+dirext;
}
```

How is this being interpreted? Is it the same as:

```
return "PROXY webproxy2.mycompany.com:8080; PROXY webproxy1.mycompany.com:8080; ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct. In JavaScript the '+' operator can be used to concatenate strings.